# Best way to display data on a B2C website?

Tags: user-behavior, user-centered-design, data

Running a real estate, consumer facing website and trying to present real estate data on both macro and micro level. Currently, engagement is low.

Considering adding side by side bulletin points to accompany chart content. Any best practices for UI/UX so users can easily discern data?

Here are screenshots - user can toggle through different types of data

[image]
[image]

Comment: In order to answer your question, I need to know what may the users looking for? what interests them? Then we can find suitable UI solutions

Comment: They want to know how prices are changing - by apartment size and overall

Answer (score 1):

Why not make a drill-down effect, you could possibly use a map to select area(s)

I would suggest having asking/sold price right next to each other.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcfm5v.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: Can you point to any samples of a site doing this?

Comment: Look at this: https://youtu.be/LO-8xiB3Z_Q?t=151

I haven't gone into the quality of the code, but it looks like he does what you are looking for.